# save unicode codepoint instead of html entities in mysql using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, unicode, utf-8

I have made all the necessary changes for database variable to `UTF8`

- character_set_client      utf8
- character_set_connection  utf8
- character_set_database        utf8
- character_set_filesystem  binary
- character_set_results     utf8
- character_set_server      utf8
- character_set_system      utf8

Also added the included the tag on jsp:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

But when a non English text is entered it get converted and store in form of html entities i.e `#&number format`

I want to enter it in `Unicode` codepoint format like `\u6709` without any `java` code converter program:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="storeMsgForm"  method="post" action="createnewmessage" >
  <input type="text" name="msg_code">
   <input type="text" name="message">
   <input type="submit" id="saveEmployee" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
  </form>

  <c:forEach var="listvalue" items="${allMsg.allmessage}">
  ${listvalue.msg_code} 
  ${listvalue.message}
  <br/>
  </c:forEach>

<% 
 if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    }
  %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser translated the special Unicode code points in input to HTML entities because of the form missing an accept-charset of UTF-8. The browser thinks the posted form results cannot be in UTF-8 for the server.

```
<form id="storeMsgForm"  method="post" action="createnewmessage" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Using this stores something like à¤¦à¥à¤µà¤¨à¤¾à¤à¤°à¥ . I just want only to save unicode for the text entered through input tags

Comment: The above is falsely received UTF-8 at the server. (Multibyte sequences interpreted as Latin-1 or such.) Its request encoding must be set to UTF-8 too. That topic is dealt with in stackoverflow. So you are really a step further. It seems your attempt to set the encoding did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Search http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll for references to Java and Spring and JSP.

`à¤¦à¥à¤µà¤¨à¤¾à¤à¤°à¥` looks like Mojibake for Devanagari; is that the language you are trying to use?

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.
- Use `<form method="post" ... accept-charset="UTF-8">` if a 'form' is involved.